# How to get values from records in a list and form a new table?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a list which contains some reocrds(the number is variable), I want to retrieve some fields from each record and build a new table.

Current data is this:

[image]

and what I want to have is something like

Asset Tag----Manufacture----Asset Number

zshavm10----IBM----12345678

zshavm11----HP----87654321

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the list into a table through the ribbon (Transform | To Table), and then expand the column by clicking on the button in the column header with the two arrows. You can then select the fields you want as your columns.